# Why does the same operation restrict linear and square root functions on different axes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I was playing around on Desmos and found something which appears odd to me.

I created a function $f(x) = x$

And another function $h(x) = (\sqrt{x})^2$

The result of $h(f(x))$ makes sense - it appears to effectively restricts the domain of $f(x)$ to $x \ge 0$

When I created the function $g(x) = (x-5)(x+5)$

$h(g(x))$ comes across as having the opposite effect as it did on $h(f(x))$ in that it now restricts the range of $g(x)$ to $y \ge 0$ and does not interact with the domain.

I thought this was a fun relationship and I want to conceptually understand it. Unfortunately, I believe that I am too elementary when it comes to mathematics to figure this one out. Is this a well known and explored concept? I would greatly appreciate any explanation!

Comment: is $h = (\sqrt{x})^2 or \sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: I think $(\sqrt x)^2$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  For instance, type `$h(x) = (\sqrt{x})^2$` to obtain $h(x) = (\sqrt{x})^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of $h$ may be one source of confusion since $h(x) = (\sqrt{x})^2 = x$ is the identity function on the domain of $h$.

Consider the functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x - 3$ and $g: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = \sqrt{x} + 4$.

The composite function $g \circ f$ is defined at those real numbers $x$ in the domain of $f$  such that $f(x)$ is in the domain of $g$.  Thus, $(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x))$ is defined when $$f(x) \geq 0 \implies x - 3 \geq 0 \implies x \geq 3$$  Therefore, the domain of $g \circ f$ is $\text{Dom}(g \circ f) = [3, \infty)$.  Since
$$(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = g(x - 3) = \sqrt{x - 3} + 4 \geq 0 + 4 = 4,$$
the range of $g \circ f$ is $\text{Ran}(g \circ f) = [4, \infty)$.

The composite function $f \circ g$ is defined at those real numbers $x$ in the domain of $g$ such that $g(x)$ is in the domain of $f$.  Since every real number is in the domain of $f$, $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$ is defined when $g(x)$ is a real number, which occurs when $x \geq 0$.  Thus, the domain of $f \circ g$ is $\text{Dom}(f \circ g) = [0, \infty)$.  Since
$$(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = f(\sqrt{x} - 4) = \sqrt{x} - 4 - 3 = \sqrt{x} - 7 \geq 0 - 7 = -7$$
the range of $f \circ g$ is $\text{Ran}(f \circ g) = [-7, \infty)$.

Now, let's look at your examples.

In what follows, the implied domain of a real-valued function is the largest subset of real numbers for which the function is defined.

The composite function $h \circ f$ is defined at those real numbers $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x)$ is in the domain of $h$.  Since $f(x) = x$ is defined at every real number $x$, the implied domain of $f$ is $\text{Dom}(f) = \mathbb{R}$.  Since $h(x) = (\sqrt{x})^2$ is defined if $x \geq 0$, the implied domain of $h$ is $\text{Dom}(h) = [0, \infty)$.

Thus, $(h \circ f)(x) = h(f(x))$ is defined at those real numbers in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x) = x \geq 0 \implies x \geq 0$.  Thus, the implied domain of $h \circ f$ is $\text{Dom}(h \circ f) = [0, \infty)$.  Since
$$(h \circ f)(x) = h(f(x)) = h(x) = (\sqrt{x})^2 = x$$
for those $x$ in the domain of $h \circ f$, the range of $h \circ f$ is $\text{Ran}(h \circ f) = [0, \infty)$.

The composite function $h \circ g$ is defined at those values in the domain of $g$ such that $g(x)$ in the domain of $h$.  Since $g(x) = (x - 5)(x + 5)$ is defined for every real number, the implied domain of $g$ is $\text{Dom}(g) = \mathbb{R}$.  Since the implied domain of $h$ is $\text{Dom}(h) = [0, \infty)$, $(h \circ g)(x) = h(g(x))$ is defined at those real numbers $x$ in the domain of $g$ such that $g(x)$ is in the domain of $h$, which implies that
$$g(x) = (x - 5)(x + 5) \geq 0 \implies x \geq 5~\text{or}~x \leq -5$$
Therefore, the domain of $h \circ g$ is $\text{Dom}(h \circ g) = (-\infty, 5] \cup [5, \infty)$.  Since
$$(h \circ g)(x) = h(g(x)) = h((x - 5)(x + 5)) = \left(\sqrt{(x - 5)(x + 5)}\right)^2 = (x - 5)(x + 5)$$
for those values of $x$ in its domain, the range of $h \circ g$ is $\text{Ran}(h \circ g) = [0, \infty)$ since only nonnegative values of $(x - 5)(x + 5)$ are in the domain of $h \circ g$.